# How do you get possible transitions from the current animation?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mecanim

I have several trigger animations which start an animation which are divided into three separate states (in, main and out). The animations would ordinarily play like so:

Idle (trigger)-> in -> main -> out -> Idle

I want to be able to abort the main animation state and cross-fade to the out state.

Using [CrossFadeInFixedTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.Director.IAnimatorControllerPlayable.CrossFadeInFixedTime.html) I can easily cross fade to a named state but I'm having trouble to dynamically find the name of the 'out' transition. The current animation state doesn't seem to have any information about potential transitions so other than using a super-strict naming convention, how can I figure out through code what transitions are available from the current animation state?

Ideally, I want to be able to iterate through the animation tree and look at what clips are ahead.